# For integer $x \ge 1$, does it follow that $\left(\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^2+2x}\right)^{x+1} > \frac{x+2}{x+1}$

Tags: derivatives, inequality

Would I be correct that the answer here is yes?

Here is my thinking:

- For $x \ge 1$, $\dfrac{x+2}{x+1}$ is strictly decreasing.
- For $x \ge 1$, $\left(\dfrac{x^2 + 2x + 1}{x^2 + 2x}\right)^{x+1}$ is strictly increasing
- $\dfrac{16}{9} > \dfrac{3}{2}$

To show that $\left(\dfrac{x^2 + 2x + 1}{x^2 + 2x}\right)^{x+1}$ is strictly increasing I take the derivative which is positive for $x > 0$

Comment: Actually, $\left(\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^2+2x}\right)^{x+1}$ is decreasing too.

Comment: Thanks.  I must have made a mistake when I took the derivative.

Comment: Hint:  $$\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^2+2x}=1+\frac1{x^2+2x}$$ and $(1+y)^n\geq 1+ny.$

Comment: You have asked WolframAlpha to compute $f'(x)$ and it is indeed increasing. It is also negative, and therefore $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Very nice application of [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)! I think your comment should be the official answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commenters have pointed out, the left side is not increasing, but decreasing.

You can see this by showing:

$$\left(\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^2+2x}\right)^{(x+1)^2}\to e,$$ so the left side of your inequality is in the range of $e^{1/(x+1)},$ and converges to $1.$

---

[Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) says that if $y\geq -1$ and $n$ is a non-negative integer, then:

$$(1+y)^n\geq 1+ny\tag1$$
We only need it for $y> 0,$ where $(1)$ obviously follows from the binomial theorem.

In your case, $n=x+1, y=\frac{1}{x^2+2x}$ gives you:

$$\left(\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^2+2x}\right)^{x+1}\geq 1+\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x}>1+\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+1}=1+\frac1{x+1}=\frac{x+2}{x+1}$$